# How to get full file path from google drive using java

Tags: google-drive-api

I am java developer .I  integrated google drive to my application using google app client_id and client_secrect .
Based on this client_id i got the access token of the user .After getting the access token.I used the following code to get files and folders from drive.

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
System.out.println(inventoryIntegrationConfig.getAccessToken());

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(inventoryIntegrationConfig.getAccessToken());

Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
.setApplicationName("Akoonu")
.setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

Files.List request = service.files().list();
.
.
.
.
```

I received file and folder download url and file name successfully .But i can't get the full file path of google drive.Like for example 
BaseFolder/SubFolder1/Subofsubfolder/testfile.txt.
here my expected output is path: BaseFolder/SubFolder1/Subofsubfolder/

I can't get the full file path from any Drive class.Can you you tell me how to get the full file path?
Which method we need to use to get full file path?

Please help me here.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike traditional filesystems, Google Drive doesn't really have a concept of full folder path or absolute file locations. A file can be located in zero or more folders. Agile may have no direct association with the owner's "My Drive".

So to answer your question, you'd need to files.get() your file in question. Then do the same files.get() for each of the folder IDs listed in `parents`. Continue to get any parents until you've reached the My Drive root folder or a folder with no parents and there's your file path.

Depending on the folder structure complexity, it may be faster and more efficient to just do a files.list() for the user getting file/folder IDs and parents. It'll take longer than a get request but once done you should have all the data you need to determine the folder paths.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to call/get the full file path. First lets clear up some details regarding the full path of the file. Stop thinking of folders and path, and think of the terms like label( parent and collection).

> **Parents**
>
> The IDs of the parent folders which contain the file.
> If not specified as part of a create request, the file will be placed directly in the My Drive folder. Update requests must use the **addParents** and **removeParents** parameters to modify the values.

A file can have more than one parent, each parent in turn can have one or more parent/label/collection. To get the "file path", we need to recursively get the parents of its parent. According to the SO ticket below answered by pinoyyid, "Remember that a file can have multiple parents, each of which can also have multiple parents, thus a file can have multiple paths."

Using Google Drive, disregard the terms path/folder but rather its simply just a property of a file.

Here is an [Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/19946-get-folder-path-of-files) that created a workaround on getting the parents/collection of the file and a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853605/how-to-find-whole-path-of-google-apps-drive-documents-using-deprecated-apis-3-0) for further information. I hope it helps.