# How to get absolute path of a document and file from Google Drive Using Java Drive Rest V2 API?

Tags: java, rest, api, google-drive-api

I'm working on **Google Drive Integration** using **Java Drive Rest V2 API**, I'm able to get most of the document/file metadata properties except path of the document/file.

I referred following StackOverflow questions as well:

- [How to get full file path from google drive using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371609/how-to-get-full-file-path-from-google-drive-using-java)
- [What's the right way to find files by “full path” in Google Drive API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266168/whats-the-right-way-to-find-files-by-full-path-in-google-drive-api-v2)

In Both links solutions indicate that I have to create a separate method to achieve this requirement, It means there is no direct method provided by Drive Rest V2 API to get file path.

Please guide me and suggest your suggestion on this.

Thank you,

Arpit

Comment: no such concept of paths in google drive.files can have multiple parents

Comment: Hi, @ZigMandel Thanks for your reply. It's mean I have to write a custom method like "getFilePath(service,file)" and iterate file up to its super parent [using file.getParents()] to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sharing my solution which will be helpful to others :)...

After several google searches and from Google Drive Documentation for **Java Drive Rest V2 API**, I got to know that there is no method to call/get the full file path.

So I created following two custom method to achieve my question solution:

1. "**getFilePath(drive, file)**" with String return type.
2. "**getfoldersList(drive, parentReferencesList, folderList)**" with List of String return type.

Below is the Code Snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive service = getDriveService();
    try {
        // Print the file path and name.
        FileList result = service.files().list().execute();
        List<File> files = result.getItems();

        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");

            for (File file : files) {
                if (!(file.getMimeType().contains("folder"))) {
                    String filePath = null;

                    if (!(file.getParents().isEmpty())) {
                        filePath = getFilePath(service, file);
                    }

                    System.out.println("path: " + filePath);
                    System.out.println("name: " + file.getTitle());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("== END ==");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private static String getFilePath(Drive drive, File file) throws IOException {
    String folderPath = "";
    String fullFilePath = null;

    List<ParentReference> parentReferencesList = file.getParents();
    List<String> folderList = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> finalFolderList = getfoldersList(drive, parentReferencesList, folderList);
    Collections.reverse(finalFolderList);

    for (String folder : finalFolderList) {
        folderPath += "/" + folder;
    }

    fullFilePath = folderPath + "/" + file.getTitle();

    return fullFilePath;
}

private static List<String> getfoldersList(Drive drive, List<ParentReference> parentReferencesList, List<String> folderList) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < parentReferencesList.size(); i++) {
        String id = parentReferencesList.get(i).getId();

        File file = drive.files().get(id).execute();
        folderList.add(file.getTitle());

        if (!(file.getParents().isEmpty())) {
            List<ParentReference> parentReferenceslist2 = file.getParents();
            getfoldersList(drive, parentReferenceslist2, folderList);
        }
    }
    return folderList;
}
```

--

Thanks,

Arpit Bora

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Parents.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/get). A successful request returns a link to both parent and the file itself. Here's a sample response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#parentReference",
 "id": "0Bw-w9jw2bwglbzlvMVh2cll2dmM",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1-ABCDEzyvp9NFmWz7h6ssgkTKHytO1Nq4SNIboDW8A/parents/0Bw-w9jw2bwglbzlvMVh2cll2dmM",
 "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/ABCDEjw2bwglbzlvMVh2cll2dmM",
 "isRoot": false
}
```

Here's the JAVA implementation from the docs:

```
 private static boolean isFileInFolder(Drive service, String folderId,
      String fileId) throws IOException {
    try {
      service.parents().get(fileId, folderId).execute();
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
      if (e.getStatusCode() == 404) {
        return false;
      } else {
        System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
        throw e;
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
      throw e;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @noogui for your reply, Your suggestion leads me to achieve my requirement. I'll post my solution soon.